# How to pass saved models to caretEnsemble

Tags: r, r-caret

Reasonably new to this so sorry if I'm being thick.
Is there a way to pass existing models to caretEnsemble?

I have several models, run on the same training data, that I would like to ensemble with caretEnsemble.
Each model takes several hours to run, so I save them, then reload them when needed rather than re-run.

```
model_xgb <- train(oi_in_4_24_months~., method="xgbTree", data=training, trControl=train_control)
saveRDS(model_xgb, "model_xgb.rds")

model_logit <- train(oi_in_4_24_months~., method="LogitBoost", data=training, trControl=train_control)
saveRDS(model_logit, "model_logit.rds")

model_xgb <- readRDS("model_xgb.rds")
model_logit <- readRDS("model_logit.rds")
```

I want to pass these saved models to caretEnsemble, but as far as I can make out I can only pass a list of model types, e.g. "LogitBoost", "xgbTree", and caretEnsemble will both run the initial models, then ensemble them. 
Is there a way to pass existing models, trained on the same data, to caretEnsemble?

The package author has an example script (https://gist.github.com/zachmayer/5152157) that suggests the following:

```
all_models <- list(model_xgb, model_logit)
names(all_models) <- sapply(all_models, function(x) x$method)
greedy <- caretEnsemble(all_models, iter=1000L)
```

But that produces an error 
"Error: is(list_of_models, "caretList") is not TRUE".
I think that use of caretList previously wasn't compulsory, but now is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you still need the solution to this but answering for anyone else that has the same question.

You can add models to be used by `caretEnsemble` or `caretStack` by using `as.caretList(list(rpart2 = model_list1, gbm = model_list2))`

But remember to use the same indexes for cross-validation/bootstrapping. 'If the indexes were different (or some stuff were not stored as "not/wrongly" specified in trainControl), it will throw an error when trying to use caretEnsemble or caretStack. Which is the expected behavior, obviously.' [This issue](https://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble/issues/104) on github has very clear and simple instructions.

Comment: Yes it's been a few years now, and so I don't have that work handy to test your solution, seems sensible though. Thanks for posting :)